# outliner doesn't show selected object if Viewport Display is disabled

Tags: outliner

If I disable an objects "Viewport Display" and then select it in an outliner that filters on "All" Objects, it will not be listed in an outliner that filters on "Selected" Objects.  This can make it difficult to build a list of selected objects to operate on that I don't want to display (for reasons like performance and View-> Frame-All).

As I click on each object, I am able to operate on its properties and do see a selection highlight (grayed highlight in outlier with All Objects).

Is there a way around this?   Doesn't this seem like unexpected behavior?

[image: outliner]

Comment: Hello :). This is perhaps a bit unintuitive behavior of Blender. Objects disabled in viewport cannot be 'selected' (you can't add modifiers, physics, etc...). It doesn't make much sense imho, but it is intended behavior :).